# Working out addition Formula of Months in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is there any sort of formula that can sum up together how much of the actual dates are in 1 Column? Hazy explanation but I'll explain;

So you have in a column, 01 May 2016, 02 May 2016, 06 May 2016, 20 May 2016, 30 May 2016, 05 June 2016, 06 June 2016, 06 June  2016...so there's five in the month May and just three for the month of June. Is there any way or doing a formula to calculate this during certain dates?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Not at all lol, I'm trying to make it easier to calculate how many items are in 1 certain month as they're are different dates down the row

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pivot table. Drag date into the rows and into the values, then group by month (and year if required).

Or use SumProduct. Create a list of dates that represent each month. Real dates, not text. Consider the following screenshot. The dates in C2 and C3 are for the first of the respective month, formatted to show just the month and year.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(YEAR($A$2:$A$11)=YEAR(C2)),--(MONTH($A$2:$A$11)=MONTH(C2)))
```

[image]

Don't use whole columns in the Sumproduct. A pivot table might be the easier approach, since it will add the new months automatically when you refresh after adding new data, whereas you would manually have to prepare the comparison months for the Sumproduct.

Comment: If that helped, please do your bit and mark it as the answer as described in the [Tour](http://superuser.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is to set up a “helper column”
to extract the month from each date, and then use `COUNTIF`
to count the occurrences of any particular (month) value in that helper column.

[image]

If your data span multiple years,
this will count the rows that fall into May *of any year*,
June *of any year*, etc. 
If you want to count only a specific month (in a specific year),
define the helper column to be `=100*YEAR(A2)+MONTH(A2)`,
and then count the occurrences of 201605, 201606, etc.